# concurrency task with delayed assignment of implementation

Tags: c++, concurrency

I have an app whose task impl needs to be set inside a switch statement. This means the task gets default-constructed before going into the switch and there is no implementation. Once I'm in the switch, I want to set the task impl (see t.get statement). The result, however, is an exception thrown BECAUSE there is no implementation. Chicken and the egg problem:

```
#include <ppltasks.h>

using namespace concurrency;
class Resource
{
public:
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  // Create a task.
  Resource r;
  task< Resource > t;
  switch( 2 )
  {
  case 2:
    t.get() = r; // runtime error "throw invalid_operation("get() cannot be called on a default constructed task.")
    break;
  }
  t.wait();
  return 0;
}
```

I played around with _SetImpl but couldn't get it to work. Any ideas as to what is wrong? I would think there would be a .set( T & t ) function to set the impl.

Comment: Here is the piece of C++ knowledge I was missing in order to set the concurrency task impl inside a switch statement.

Comment: Here is the piece of C++ knowledge I was missing in order to set the concurrency task impl inside a switch statement: see Thomas's answer to Stackoverflow question, "Why can't variables be declared in a switch statement?" By adding braces, the concurrency::task may be moved to the relevant case statement.